# Python and POST data

Tags: python, http, post

In PHP I simply write:

```
$bob = $_POST['bob'];
```

How do I do the same in Python?

And yes, I do normally check that it exists etc, I'm just stripping it down specifically to the functionality I am after.

---

Edit: I am not using a framework

Comment: Well, that really depends on what framework you are using. Elaborate?

Comment: I am not using a framework, if I was then I'd have said so :)

Comment: may be you want to add "http" to the tags, I'm not sure that the tags "post" and "get" applies to this question.

Comment: I agree with William. Your question should have been more clear. There isn't enough context, regardless if you implied any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest method is the 'cgi' module:

```
import cgi
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
data['bob']
```

But the context you are executing in (frameworks you're using, WSGI or even (heaven forbid) mod_python) may have different, more efficient or more direct methods of access.